# Is there a way for php to make a file name match an id

Tags: php

here is my code

```
<div id="lara"><a href="http://anywhere.com/work/lara.jpg">some crap</a></div>

<div id="jerk"><a href="http://anywhere.com/work/jerk.jpg">some crap</a></div>

<div id="yessir"><a href="http://anywhere.com/work/yessir.jpg">some crap</a></div>
```

basically i'm wondering if there is a way to replace the filename (of the image) with some php that will dynamically add the id of the parent div in its place.

why you ask? i have several links like this where the id matches the filename, and i feel as though i should not have to manually type each file name in. I believe i've seen this done in ASP, but am not sure what the method is called, or if it's possible in php.

help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood you:

```
$arr = array("foo", "foo1", "foo2");
foreach($foo as $item){
  echo "<div id='$item'><a href='www.something.com/$item'>$item</a></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way I could think if would be to make it into a function..

```
function printDiv($name) {
  echo "<div id='$name'><a href='http://anywhere.com/work/$name.jpg'>some crap</a></div>";
}
```

To call it, do the following:

```
printDiv('lara');
```

You might want to modify this to return a string instead of echoing depending on what you're doing..

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this in PHP is if you have the ids in a variable in PHP.

```
<div id="<?=$name?>"><a href="http://anywhere.com/work/<?=$name?>.jpg">some crap</a>
```

Otherwise you will have to do it in Javascript, maybe with something like jQuery: http://jquery.com/